# Factorybot, create records common polymorphic relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How do I `create(:listing, :for_car)` and `create(:firm, :for_car)`, but allow them to have the same common car record?

Ideally, I would like to do `create(:listing)` and have it create, User, and then Car (belongs_to User), then Listing (belongs_to Car), and then Firm (belongs_to Car). In this instance, Car is the same exact record, not two different Car records.

So I don't have to have multiple `create` methods called. How can I accomplish this?

```
FactoryBot.define do

  factory :user, class: "User" do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { "bla" }
    password_confirmation { "bla" }
  end

  factory :car, class: "Car" do
    color { "black" }
    association :user, factory: :user
  end

  factory :truck, class: "Truck" do
    size { "15" }
    association :user, factory: :user
  end

  factory :bike, class: "Bike" do
    style { "road" }
    association :user, factory: :user
  end

  factory :listing, class: "Listing" do
    for_car # default

    trait :for_car do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end

    trait :for_truck do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end

    trait :for_bike do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end
  end

  factory :firm, class: "Firm" do

    for_car # default

    trait :for_car do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end

    trait :for_truck do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end

    trait :for_bike do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end
  end

  factory :store, class: "Store" do
    for_car # default

    trait :for_car do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end

    trait :for_truck do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end

    trait :for_bike do
      association :listable, factory: :car
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might go about it like:

> car_factory.rb

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :car, class: Car do
    color { "black" }
    user
  end
end
```

(note you shouldn't need to use that verbose syntax)

> listing_factory.rb

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
factory :listing, class: "Listing" do
    car
  end
end
```

This is assuming listing has a field called `car`. FactoryBot can find the proper factory for you in this scenario.

Then in your spec you can just override defaults like so:

```rb
    let(:car) { create(:car) }
    let(:truck) { create(:truck) }
    let(:car_listing) { create(:listing) }
    let(:truck_listing) { create(:listing, car: truck) }
```

Any arguments you pass after the name of the factory in the `create` method get passed in to overwrite any defaults inside the factory.